# Angular GH Pages "Failed to load resource"

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I have an resume I am working on in angular that it hosted through Github Pages. The images I have for the left profile card and the top background work locally no problem, or if I host them on imgur etc but when I build the project with the img path in the build "/docs/assets/images" the console pulls a 404 error. I have about 3-4 hours into google searching the problem but have not nailed down a solution yet. Anyone else had this problem?
Resume Site: https://ovarmorrow.github.io/resume/

[Github repo images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mF2J.png)

Comment: Add `/resume` before the paths. The context for the paths being specified in `app.component.ts` is not taking into account your base hosting path of `/resume`.

Comment: You lead me on the right track thank you! I had to take out "/docs/" inside of my img path.
`this.navBackground = "/resume/assets/img/navBackground.jpg";`